# How to prevent images from firebase storage to be downloaded every time on filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, filter, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to load images into my web page. I have a page where I show different kinds of projects. I also provided a filter option. That is where I have my problem now. Every time users use a filter, the images from the firebase storage are downloaded again.

This is the code where I map over all my projects to show the project component.

```
{newProjects.map((project) => (
  <Project project={project} key={project.id}></Project>
))}
```

In my project component, I use the project data to download the right image.

```
const imgRef = useRef(null);
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
storageRef
  .child('images/' + project.image)
  .getDownloadURL()
  .then(function (url) {
      imgRef.current.src = url;
    }
  });

return (
  <img
    className={style.card_image}
    ref={imgRef}
    alt={project.title}
  </img>
)
```

The projects are loaded in with the right images, great! The problem now is that if a user uses a filter, the images from the projects are downloaded from firebase again. The newProjects are a state and whenever I use the filter I will set the state again.

```
const [newProjects, setNewProjects] = useState(projects);

const filter = () => {
// filter stuff...

setNewProjects(filteredProjects);
}
```

Is there a way that the images won't download every time the users use a filter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: if they get the same image, shouldn't it already be in the browser case, and thus be read form there?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are right, but for example, let's say: if the projects have a condition "finished". I filter on this condition. All the projects with the condition "finished" will stay and it doesn't download extra images. But if I remove the filter, all the projects which didn't have the condition "finished" will be downloaded again...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what projects are and how they relate to images from Storage.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Users can make projects on my webpage. They can upload an image and this image will be saved in the storage. On the projects page, I show all the projects with their image. That is what I'm trying to do in the code above. I map over all the projects and render a component for each project. In that component, I download the image from the storage and show them on the page. When I filter, the images will be downloaded again causing a lot of bandwidth on the storage

Comment: That brings me back t o my first comment: if you're setting `imgRef.current.src = url;` for the same URL, it should be coming from the cache (I think). Is that not happening for you?